# Java EE message push Dynamically

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to add a new function in my APP: when there are some messages for user, user can find it without refresh page or apply a new request.
for example: if we want to shut down server in one hour, user can find it when viewing page. 
many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Periodic Poll
- AsyncServlet
- WebSocket